# jquery/javascript blur/focus & settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

When mouse is over a product number (focus) then show some product information.
When user is not longer over a product number (blur), then wait 3 seconds, then hide details.

```
$('.productNumber').live('blur', function() {               
    setTimeout(function(){
    var divToPutData = $(this); 
    divToPutData.hide();
}, 3000);
});
```

Now user says that if user moves mouse back within those 5 seconds to stop the count down, until a blur event fires again. No sure how to do this with setTimeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout)

```
var myTimeout = null;

$('.productNumber').live('mouseover', function() {  
    //If timeout is still active, clear
    if(myTimeout != null)
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});

$('.productNumber').live('blur', function() {
    //Store the ID returned by setTimeout
    myTimout = setTimeout(function(){ divToPutData.hide(); }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: brilliant! javascript (and Mr hill) never cease to amaze me!

Comment: hhm, is myTimeOut is a global variable?

Comment: yes, it has to be or else you can't clearTimeout on it through another function

Comment: lol how many same exact answers can be given in a span of minutes?

Comment: @3n1gm4, Great question! Sort by oldest post and you'll see that mine was **first**. =)

Comment: @3n1gm4, doesn't seem to have helped me get an upvote though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the function clearTimeout.

setTimeout returns a numeric id, you can store it in a variable, and then pass it to the clearTimeout function:

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout ( function(){alert(2);}, 1000);
clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t;
$('.productNumber').live('mouseover', function() {  
    clearTimeout(t);
});

$('.productNumber').live('mouseout', function() {               
    t = setTimeout(function(){
    divToPutData.hide();
}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between mouseout and blur?

Comment: mouseleave http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mouseout.asp blur http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp, mainly because Chrome doesn’t support this when the user uses a mouse for blur. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

Answer (score 0):

have the setTimeout assigned to a variable, so you can cancel it on hover again

```
var hideTimeout;
$('.productNumber').live('blur',function() {
    hideTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        divToPutData.hide();
    }, 3000);
});
$('.productNumber').live('mouseover',function() {
    clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
    // Do the show stuff
}
```

- jQuery is not my strongest language, so you may need to modify this slightly, but this is the general approach to this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `stop()` to abort any ongoing animation

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/T7kRr/1/

**jQuery**

```
$(".productNumber").hover(
  function () {
      $(this).find(".productDesc:last").stop(true, true).show();
  }, 
  function () {
      $(this).find(".productDesc:last").delay(3000).fadeOut(); 
  }
);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="productNumber">1001<span class="productDesc" style="display:none">iPhone</span></div>
<div class="productNumber">2001<span class="productDesc" style="display:none">iPad</span></div>
<div class="productNumber">3333<span class="productDesc" style="display:none">TV</span></div>
<div class="productNumber">9999<span class="productDesc" style="display:none">HiFi</span></div>
```